# SDK version required annotation

Tags: android, annotations, compiler-warnings

I'm calling a function through reflection which is available since froyo. How can I mark that this call requires froyo?

There is the annotation `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)` but this does just prevent warnings I want to generate a warning if this version does not match.

If there is no way from the SDK site is it possible to write such an annotation? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: See also [Android bug 42194](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42194).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally forgot to mention this, but this annotation [`@RequiresApi`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/annotation/RequiresApi) was actually introduced in Support Lib v24 back in 2016, [after raising a bugreport](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36963227).

Answer (score 1):

Annotations are just metadata and need tools to actually process them, there's no lint check to do the reverse of what you want: indicating that something requires a certain API according to http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks.

If you are providing an API, it would be best to document the requirement in the Javadoc of the function so that a caller is aware that that particular call requires Froyo. In the function you should probably throw an exception if this pre condition is not satisfied or handle it in some other way.

Another option, if you are creating a library, is to set the minSdk version of that project to 8 or up.

You also could write your own lint rule that would do a custom check I guess. More details on writing lint rules are here: http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules. The downside is that users of your api have to perform some custom setup to activate the rule.

Comment: You may be right, but how does lint know that a function is aviable since version x?

Comment: You'd have to dig through the lint source code, maybe the Android SDK is annotated in some way, I haven't checked.

Comment: I checked the lint source code...Lint has this class https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/tools_r21.1/lint/libs/lint_checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/ApiLookup.java which loads the API version from $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/api/api-versions.xml

Comment: +1 for that digging that out. This is good to know but not realy what I'm looking for. If nobody has a better idea I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Maybe you can describe what you are trying to do some more. As you have formulated it now, there's no way to reuse an existing lint check or other kind of checking without a custom annotation and an annotation processor for example, it's just the way it works in Java ;)

Comment: I believe you are right, but I have the hope that somebody knows something more than we both.

Comment: Sorry for unaccepting, but this is not true anymore.